# "Verify your account" when opening Netflix's app on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, netflix

Since today (yesterday it was OK) I can't open my Netflix app on Windows 10. It actually opens for less than one second then immediately stops with the following error:

[image]

For those who do not speak French, this means:

> Verify your account
>   You may not (can't) access Netflix right now.
>   Access the Windows Store.
>                                        [ Close ]

The last sentence is a link towards the Netflix app in the Windows Store. When clicking on it, it only says that the application is installed and there is no indication that the application is out of date or something similar.

The Netflix app was there when I bought this computer with Windows 10. I had a Netflix account so I entered my credentials. Netflix on my other devices (PS4, Phone) works well. Besides my Netflix account, I have no account on that computer (no Windows account, no Microsoft account, nothing).

The speed of the "crash" and the regularity of that speed, whether I'm connected or not to the Internet, lets me think that there is no Internet access at all when this error occurs.

What is this error and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried reinstalling the app? The Win10 Netflix app often messes up for me after an update, and reinstalling it has always worked thusfar.

Comment: Awesome, happy to hear it :)